# Run giraph on Hadoop yarn 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, giraph

I'm trying to use Giraph on `hadoop 2.6.0` with yarn.

I've managed to build it by removing `STATIC_SASL_SYMBOL` in `<munge.symbols>` in the `yarn profile`. with the command :

```
sudo mvn -Phadoop_yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests package
```

Then i've setup a single node cluster with hadoop 2.6.0 and I'm able to perform the basic wordcount example.
I've copied the jar built into the directory `share/hadoop/mapreduce` to remove the `GiraphMaster` not found execption.

Now I'm trying to run the `SimpleShortestPaths` example with the command :

```
$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip input_tiny2.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/shortestpaths445 -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false -yj giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The data used is the tiny graph on the giraph quick start page and the job should takes minutes to complete but it doesn't.

The full log is at http://pastebin.com/CW1FnWz2

It's possible to make giraph work on hadoop 2.6.0 or do I have to use an earlier version ? If so which one would you suggest ?